# What is adding Con(PA) to PA good for?

Tags: logic, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

### Is there any non-trivial statement in PA + Con(PA), that was not already in PA? where PA = Peano Arithmetic

The standard model of PA (the basis of number theory) seems to be a model of PA + Con(PA) too. In this sense, is there a theorem in PA + Con(PA) that can't be proven in standard number theory?

Comment: Well, $\mathsf{PA}+\text{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ proves $\text{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$, but mere $\mathsf{PA}$ doesn't... There's almost certainly a less silly answer, but I don't know it unfortunately

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Indeed, that is what I meant by "trivial"

Comment: There is a diophantine equation where the existence of solutions is equivalent to Con(PA). Does that count?

Comment: @ZhenLin What is the equation?

Comment: It's something with lots of variables and constructed for the purpose. This is Matiyasevich's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite an answer but it is related. [Gentzen showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof) that you can prove the consistency of PA using primitive recursive arithmetic together with transfinite induction up to a countable ordinal called [$\epsilon_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_number). As I understand it, he argued that the existence of $\varepsilon_0$ was less controversial than the consistency of PA so this was a good reason to believe that PA was consistent. So instead of considering adding $\text{Con}(PA)$ let's consider adding the existence of $\varepsilon_0$.

Then there are some "natural" statements such as [Goodstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem), the [strengthened finite Ramsey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem), or the winnability of the (Kirby-Paris) [hydra game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydra_game) which can be proven using transfinite induction up to $\varepsilon_0$ (and which I believe are essentially equivalent to the existence of $\varepsilon_0$ , although I can't find a reference explicitly stating this) but which are known to be independent of PA. (If they're equivalent to the existence of $\varepsilon_0$ then this follows since PA can't prove the existence of $\varepsilon_0$, by Gentzen.)

Answer (score 0):

[this is more of a comment, but I do not have enough reputation for that]

$\mathrm{Con}_{\mathit{PA}}$ is a $\Pi_1$ statement and so, assuming it is true (i.e. $\mathit{PA}$ is consistent), it adds no new computational content to $\mathit{PA}$. In other words, $\mathit{PA}'$ cannot represent any new recursive functions than $\mathit{PA}$. (By 'represent' here I mean proving that some $\Sigma_1$-formula computing graph of the function is total.) This is a well-known result in proof theory (see, e.g., Kohlenbach's book *Applied Proof Theory*).